# Did Lord Krishna cry ever?

Tags: krishna, gods, bhagavad-gita, bhagavata-purana

As per folk stories Dear Lord Krishna cried when He meet his Friend Sudama. Another story is Krishna cried when meeting paternal brother Uddhava in Dwarka.

Is there any scriptural reference of the same when krishna cried?

Comment: I think, when Karna was executed Krishna cried for their curse.

Comment: by "cried" do u mean tears? and what does "Salwa kind executed father vasudeva" mean? it is "Salwa king was executed/killed by father Vasudeva"?

Comment: Yes removed that part from the question,  I meant tears.

Comment: @Talk I can't show the code, it ain't SO. BTW Krishna cried when Sudama after all the troubles,met him.

Comment: whooo but any scriptural reference of it?

Comment: Well guess I was right. Someone posted same thing as answer. @Talk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened when Krishna was about to take leave from his sister.

After spending some days at Indraprastha with his sister and pandavas, Krishna decided to take depart from them.

He got emotional while taking leave from his sister. His eyes got filled up with tears of affection and separation from his little love - his little sister. This brother- sister moment is so mesmerising!

[image]

This is not crying in literal sense, but this scene is quite emotional!!!

How cute Krishna was as a brother!! I can't stop adoring him.

And this is not the only time when he became sad. He felt immense pain and grief on the death of his favourite nephew ABHIMANYU.
[image]

Both the buddies got afflicted with unbearable pain. He spend restless nights.

Though he had not shed tears in actual sense but definitely he must've been crying from inside.

[image]

Off course he is vishnu, he couldn't fell down like this. Who will handle Nar if Narayana himself will broke down!!

People around him were weeping, they were all tormented by intense misery caused by the death of Abhimanyu. It was his sole duty to console them as no other was capable of doing that.

It was the Krishna who gathered up his heart, his courage and consoled Subhadra, Draupadi, uttara and others who were indulged in heart rending lamentation. He then went to Parth to make him comfortable.

He ignored his own sorrow just to make others comfortable.

His sister meant alot to him. He didn't shed tears in front of her otherwise it would make her more weak. He tried every possible way to cut down her pain, to make her came back to life.

[image]

[source](https://www.quora.com/Did-Lord-Krishna-ever-cry-for-something-someone/answer/Kumari-Ananya-%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE)

Answer (score 6):

As per [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa): Skandha 10: Chapter 80](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/80/), Lord Krishna shed tears of love when he met with Sudama:

> सख्यु: प्रियस्य विप्रर्षेरङ्गसङ्गातिनिर्वृत: ।
>
> प्रीतो **व्यमुञ्चदब्बिन्दून् नेत्राभ्यां** पुष्करेक्षण: ॥ १९ ॥
>
> The lotus-eyed Supreme Lord felt intense ecstasy upon touching the body of His dear friend [Sudāmā], the wise brāhmaṇa, and thus **He [Kṛṣṇa] shed tears of love**.

There are few other instances as well:

- When Kṛṣṇa and Balarāma met with Nanda and Yashoda

  > O hero of the Kurus, Kṛṣṇa and Balarāma embraced Their foster parents
  >   and bowed down to them, but **Their throats were so choked up with tears
  >   of love that the two Lords could say nothing**. ~[ŚB 10.82.34](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/82/34/)
- During childhood

  > Being very angry and biting His reddish lips with His teeth, Kṛṣṇa, with false **tears in His eyes**, broke the container of yogurt with a piece of stone. Then He entered a room and began to eat the freshly churned butter in a solitary place.
  >
  > When caught by mother Yaśodā, Kṛṣṇa became more and more afraid and admitted to being an offender. As she looked upon Him, she saw that **He was crying**, **His tears mixing with the black ointment around His eyes**, and as He rubbed His eyes with His hands, He smeared the ointment all over His face. Mother Yaśodā, catching her beautiful son by the hand, mildly began to chastise Him. ~[ŚB 10.9](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/9/)